# Get a carousal table value in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project where in there is a carousal table, that table has some cars details.

When I click on that table, there is another div coming up(a modal) with content as `Some text in the new Modal..`.

Here instead of this, is there a way to get the `MAKE` value from the table?

Here is my working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxaxf28q/3/)

Thanks

Comment: Take a look, and let me know if this works for you - if it does, I'll add it as an answer --> https://jsfiddle.net/oxaxf28q/2/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, Bro, this is what I need, but a small mistake (from me). I've updated your response fiddle. now when I go to the next card and click it is showing `volkswagon`, but it show `Mitsubishi`

Comment: bRIMOs has got you covered with the answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , you can't use the same id for  all of your table (`id="tabClass"`) instead of id replace it by `class="tabClass"` , then call the  `onclick="showModal1(this)"` (***`this` to refer to current clicked table***)  in all of your table , then once clicking there you query the make class td then you get it's text content as below :

```
function showModal1(e) {
  var make = e.querySelector('.make').textContent;
  modal1.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Make : '+make;
  modal1.style.display = "block";
}
```

see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxaxf28q/5/)

Or the below snippet :

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "";
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("chat");
var btn1 = document.getElementsByTagName("tabClass");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
if(btn)
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

function showModal1(e) {
  var make = e.querySelector('.make').textContent;
 console.log(e.querySelector('.make').innerHTML);
  modal1.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Make : '+make;
  modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
if(span)
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
span1.onclick = function() {
  modal1.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#chat,
#chat:after,
.chatbox {
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out
}

#chat,
#close-chat,
.minim-button,
.maxi-button,
.chat-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px
}

#chat,
#close-chat,
.chat-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px
}

#chat,
#close-chat,
.chatbox {
  border: 1px solid #A8A8A8
}

#chat:after,
#chat:before {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  content: ""
}

.chatbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 65%;
  height: 85%;
  bottom: 0.5%;
  right: 1%;
  margin: 0 0 -1500px;
  background: white;
}

#close-chat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 2
}

#minim-chat,
#maxi-chat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1
}

.minim-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 32px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  width: 20px;
}

.maxi-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 32px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fefefe;
}

.chat-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 140px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#chat {
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0)
}

#chat:before {
  border-width: 10px 11px 0 0;
  border-color: #A8A8A8 transparent transparent;
  left: 7px;
  bottom: -10px
}

#chat:after {
  border-width: 9px 8px 0 0;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent;
  left: 8px;
  bottom: -8px
}

#chat:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-pulse-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate
}

#chat:hover:after {
  border-color: #ddd transparent transparent!important
}

.animated-chat {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in
}

@-webkit-keyframes tada {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
  10%,
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9)rotate(-3deg)
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1)rotate(3deg)
  }
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1)rotate(-3deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)rotate(0)
  }
}

@keyframes tada {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
  10%,
  20% {
    transform: scale(.9)rotate(-3deg)
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1)rotate(3deg)
  }
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.1)rotate(-3deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)rotate(0)
  }
}

.tada {
  -webkit-animation-name: tada;
  animation-name: tada
}

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1)
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1)
  }
}

.chat-form {
  position: absolute;
  /* bottom: 0px; */
  bottom: 0;
  /* margin-top: 4%; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul li {
  max-width: 80%;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 4%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #00819E;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  /* max-width: calc(100% - 20px); */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.lexResponse:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 21px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #00819E;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -10.5px;
  margin-left: -21px;
}

.me:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 21px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: lightskyblue;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -10.5px;
  margin-right: -21px;
}

.me {
  float: right;
  background: lightskyblue;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 8px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 6%;
}

.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}

.chat-text {
  text-align: center;
}

#textinput {
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 95%;
}

.backgroundColor {
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 176, 240, 0.7);
  z-index: 999;
}

.chatHeader {
  position: absolute;
  /* position: relative; */
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #101010;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 9%;
}

.chatBody {
  margin-top: 13%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 70%;
  /* margin-bottom: 50px; */
}

.col2,
.col1 {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center
}

.w3-display-right {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.w3-display-left {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

table {
  border: 0px;
}

table td {
  color: black;
}

.make {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.x {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #50C9C3 10%, #96DEDA 90%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #50C9C3 10%, #96DEDA 90%);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #50C9C3 10%, #96DEDA 90%);
}

td.col2 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

td.col1 {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-variant: small-caps
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal,
.modal1 {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content1 {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* The Close Button */

.close,
.close1 {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus,
.close1:hover,
.close1:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* .w3-animate-zoom {
   animation: animatezoom 0.6s
  } */

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- <span class="close">&times;</span> -->
    <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox" style="margin: 0px;">
      <div>Based on your requirements here are the top 10 cars that I can recommend you
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="x" id="x">
          <table class="tabClass" onclick="showModal1(this)" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Make</td>
                <td class="col2 make">volkswagen</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Model</td>
                <td class="col2">tiguan</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Vehicle Size</td>
                <td class="col2">compact</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Doors</td>
                <td class="col2">4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Hp</td>
                <td class="col2">200</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Price</td>
                <td class="col2">34445</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="tabClass" onclick="showModal1(this)" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; display: none;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Make</td>
                <td class="col2 make">mitsubishi</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Model</td>
                <td class="col2">outlander sport</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Vehicle Size</td>
                <td class="col2">compact</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Doors</td>
                <td class="col2">4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Hp</td>
                <td class="col2">168</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Price</td>
                <td class="col2">25995</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="tabClass" onclick="showModal1(this)" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; display: none;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Make</td>
                <td class="col2 make">buick</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Model</td>
                <td class="col2">encore</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Vehicle Size</td>
                <td class="col2">compact</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Doors</td>
                <td class="col2">4</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Hp</td>
                <td class="col2">138</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="col1">Price</td>
                <td class="col2">31285</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <span class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮❮</span>
        <span class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯❯</span>
        <br>Would you want to know your nearby Car dealers?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal1">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content1">
   <span class="close1">&times;</span>
   <p>Some text in the new Modal..</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Does this fix your issue :)